# How to store an object in the Laravel database

Tags: php, laravel

I have a list of menus as follows
When I move the menus using the Nestable library, an object is sent to the backend as shown below.
How can I save it in the database?

[image: Data Base]

```json
[{"id":1},{"id":2,"children":[{"id":3},{"id":4},{"id":5,"children":[{"id":6},{"id":7},{"id":8}]},{"id":9},{"id":10}]},{"id":11},{"id":12}]
```

[image: Menu List]

Comment: you can convert your data into json format and save it in table

Answer (score 1):

You could save it as a JSON in database

for example in your migration

```
$table->json('YOUR-COLUMN-NAME')->nullable();
```

and in your model

```
    protected $casts = [
        'YOUR-COLUMN-NAME' => 'array',
]
```

Answer (score 1):

just encode your array into json and save it into the table like

```
$data=json_encode([{"id":1},{"id":2,"children":[{"id":3},{"id":4},{"id":5,"children":[{"id":6},{"id":7},{"id":8}]},{"id":9},{"id":10}]},{"id":11},{"id":12}]);

$model->create(['data'=>$data]);
```

then you can retrive the data by decoding like

```
$obj=Model::first();
$data=json_decode($obj->data);
```

you can also check [json_encode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) and [json_decode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) for more details

Answer (score 0):

As written in the official documentation, Array & JSON Casting is what you need (to read more and see examples click [here](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-mutators#array-and-json-casting))

> The array cast is particularly useful when working with columns that are stored as serialized JSON. For example, if your database has a JSON or TEXT field type that contains serialized JSON, adding the array cast to that attribute will automatically deserialize the attribute to a PHP array when you access it on your Eloquent model.